# What are vintage magic cards worth?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have some very old magic cards with no symbols how can I find out what they are worth or if they are rare?

Answer (score 0):

> I have some very old magic cards with no symbols how can I find out what they are worth or if they are rare?

You can start by Googling their name and doing some research on their price and specs.

You can also check on pages that focus on TCG/CCG, like for example [Troll & Toad](https://www.trollandtoad.com/) (*disclaimer*: just an example, nothing related to them). There you can search for cards, see their prices and even sell or buy.

You can also go to your local store of where people gather to play Board and Card games, and ask around to see if there is anyone interested in acquiring your cards and willing to negotiate.